# Figure out grouping logic for this Spark Scala Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark DataFrame (DF) which looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------------------------
id | b                      | c  | d          | e         |
----------------------------------------------------------
1  | "ok"                   | 9  | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
1  | "not ok"               | 10 | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
1  | "sure"                 | 1  | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
2  | "not sure"             | 2  | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
2  | "not so sure"          | 12 | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
1  | "sure bleh"            | 1  | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
3  | "not sure"             | 5  | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
3  | "not so sure"          | 25 | "dontcare" | "dontcare"|
----------------------------------------------------------
```

I am trying to create a new DF by transforming this one in **Spark Scala** in the following way:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
id | grouping                                                       | count |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | (("ok",9),("not ok", 10), ("sure", 1), ("sure bleh", 1))       |   4   |        
2  | (("not sure",2),("not so sure" , 12))                          |   2   |        
3  | (("not sure",5),("not so sure" , 25))                          |   2   |        
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What would be the best way to create this DF using **Spark Scala**? I am stuck while trying to figure out this grouping logic.
I have tried this so far:

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","\t").csv("test.csv")
df.show

val finalDF = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(array("b", "c")).as("grouping")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a column as array type first, and then use `groupBy`.

```
val df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter","\t").csv("test.csv")
df.show

val finalDF = df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list(array("b", "c")).as("grouping"), count("*").as("count")).orderBy("id")
finalDF.show(false)
finalDF.printSchema
```

```
+---+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
|id |grouping                                          |count|
+---+--------------------------------------------------+-----+
|1  |[[ok, 9], [not ok, 10], [sure, 1], [sure bleh, 1]]|4    |
|2  |[[not sure, 2], [not so sure, 12]]                |2    |
|3  |[[not sure, 5], [not so sure, 25]]                |2    |
+---+--------------------------------------------------+-----+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- grouping: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: string (containsNull = true)
 |-- count: long (nullable = false)
```

Comment: You forgot the count column: ".agg(count("*").as("count"))"

Comment: No problem. One last remark, you can also do: "collect_list(array("b", "c")).as("grouping")" 
So you don't have to create the "temp" column.